# Cannot excute jar correctly - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror, awt-eventqueue

I executed my file.jar in my terminal and it show for me this message

java -jar demoBioMini.jar

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/suprema/BioMiniSDK

And this is the full error for my problem

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/suprema/BioMiniSDK
    at demoBioMini.<init>(demoBioMini.java:2199)
    at demoBioMini$27.run(demoBioMini.java:2186)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at
```

I am using all libraries correctly

Comment: *I am using all libraries correctly*: If you were, you wouldn't have that exception, would you? The jar file doesn't have the correct Class-Path manifest entry, or the required jar files are not where they should be. What's the content of the manifest? Where are the libraries located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check all library or classes present in demoBioMini.jar file
extract and check again

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to execute demoBioMini.jar? You missed out the classpath, "./java/BioMiniSDK.jar"

Try this.

```
$ java -classpath "./java/BioMiniSDK.jar;./demoBioMini.jar" demoBioMini
```

Or, you can run demoBioMini_Java.bat in the same directory.

```
$ demoBioMini_Java.bat
```